# Label rows for range facets sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, range, sunspot, facet

I'm using sunspot solr in my rails app to handle searching and I've set up a facet to allow searching through price ranges. How can I create labels to use for the row values in the views. This [article here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-rails--cms-20638) suggests using conditional statements but I'm not sure how I would do this.

So for example instead of the values appearing as:

```
0.0..75.0
75.0..150.0
150.0..225.0
225.0..300.0
```

etc.. I want to display them as:

```
$0 - $75
$75 - $150
$150 - $225
$225 - $300
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

**/models/listing.rb**

```
searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :marker_list, :boost => 2
    string :marker_list, :multiple => true, :stored => true
    double :price
end
```

**/controllers/listings_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @listings = Listing.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page]).per_page(60)

    @search = Listing.solr_search do
        fulltext params[:listings]

        facet :price, :range => 0..2000, :range_interval => 75
        with(:price, Range.new(*params[:price_range].split("..").map(&:to_i))) if params[:price_range].present?

    end

    @results = Listing.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id)).page(params[:page]).per_page(60)
end
```

**/views/listings/index.html.erb**

```
<% for row in @search.facet(:price).rows %>
    <span class="bprice">
        <%= link_to row.value, :price_range => row.value, :search => params[:listings] %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just a question of regex replacement?

Try this:

```
new_string = old_string.gsub(/\.0\.\./,"$ - ").gsub(/\.0/,"$")
# old_string = "0.0..75.0"
# new_string = "0$ - 75$"
```

That would probably mean in your code

```
    <%= link_to (row.value).to_s.gsub(/\.0\.\./,"$ - ").gsub(/\.0/,"$"), 
                :price_range => row.value, :search => params[:listings] %>
```

Comment: It gives me this error `undefined method 'gsub' for 0.0..75.0:Range`